# Simple TRIGGER throwing error and stop the execution

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this trigger in MySQL

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS BeforeGivingRight;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER BeforeGivingRight
BEFORE INSERT ON right_code 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE num_rows INT NULL;
    SELECT count(right_code) FROM valid_rights WHERE right_code  =
                                            new.user_right.right INTO num_rows;
    
    IF num_rows = 0
    THEN
        set msg = concat('Error: That right is not allowed!',
                                      cast(new.user_right.right as char));
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

And its gives me this error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
    to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL; SELECT
    count(right_code) FROM valid_rights WHERE right_code  = new.user_' at line 5
```

What is wrong here? What I want to do is, before I insert some right (201 for example), check in `valid_rights` whether it exists, using triggers.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the *keyword* `DEFAULT`. Use `0` instead of `NULL`.

```
DECLARE total_sale INT DEFAULT 0;
```

**[See HERE: Variables in Stored Procedures](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/variables-in-stored-procedures.aspx)**

Comment: it was my awareness ... but seriously, why it tells me about  LINE 5 and `SELECT count(right_code) FROM valid_rights WHERE right_code  = new.user_` witch is on line 8 ?? it makes my head go wild ...

Comment: @Empeus to answer your question about line numbers, honestly I don't know about it. If I see errors generated, I only find `...right syntax to use near...` not the line number. hehe

Comment: @Empeus well, it is obvious, the error message states `...for the right syntax to use near 'NULL; ...`, well, `NULL` is of course in the previous line..

Comment: and it is obvious that mysql is very cryptic, just look over my EDIT

Comment: @Empeus is your trigger ok now?

Comment: yes, but i'm disappointed about mysql's type of showing errors, they are very cryptic

Answer (score 1):

So when you want a trigger that trows an exception you use this :

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS BeforeGivingRight;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER BeforeGivingRight
BEFORE INSERT ON user_rights 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE num_rows INT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE msg VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT "";
    SELECT count(valid_rights.right_code) FROM valid_rights WHERE right_code  = new.right INTO num_rows;

    IF num_rows = 0
    THEN
        set msg = concat('Error: That right is not allowed!', cast(new.right as char));
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

As a work around: if tables are InnoDb then you could use foreign key to restrict nonexistent values. Just add foreign key to `user_rights` table, and error will be raised by server.

For example -

```
ALTER TABLE right_code
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_right_code FOREIGN KEY (`right`)
    REFERENCES valid_rights(right_code) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

Also, make the field `valid_rights`.`right_code` unique, if it is not.